# Ruby - Delete the last character in a file?

Tags: ruby, file-io

Seems like it must be easy, but I just can't figure it out. How do you delete the very last character of a file using Ruby IO?

I took a look at the answer for [deleting the last line of a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190383/how-to-delete-last-line-of-file-in-ruby) with Ruby but didn't fully understand it, and there must be a simpler way.

Any help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is [`File.truncate`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/File.html#method-c-truncate):

> **truncate(file_name, integer) → 0**
>
> Truncates the file `file_name` to be at most `integer` bytes long. Not available on all platforms.

So you can say things like:

```
File.truncate(file_name, File.size(file_name) - 1)
```

That should truncate the file with a single system call to adjust the file's size in the file system without copying anything.

Note that *not available on all platforms* caveat though. `File.truncate` should be available on anything unixy (such as Linux or OSX), I can't say anything useful about Windows support.

Comment: I'm on OSX and this works perfectly. Very simple and readable, thank you!

Comment: Worked for me on Wndows. One tripfall: I wanted to remove the last line break and I needed to use `File.truncate(file_name, File.size(file_name) - 2)` (Remove CR+LF)

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are referring to a text file.  The usual way of changing such is to read it, make the changes, then write a new file:

```
  text = File.read(in_fname)
  File.write(out_fname, text[0..-2])
```

Insert the name of the file you are reading from for `in_fname` and the name of the file you are writing to for 'out_fname'.  They can be the same file, but if that's the intent it's safer to write to a temporary file, copy the temporary file to the original file then delete the temporary file. That way, if something goes wrong before the operations are completed, you will probably still have either the original or temporary file. `text[0..-2]` is a string comprised of all characters read except for the last one. You could alternatively do this:

```
  File.write(out_fname, File.read(in_fname, File.stat(in_fname).size-1))
```

Comment: You don't think it exists, or couldn't find it?  [IO.write](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html#method-i-write).  `File.superclass #=> IO`.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comment because I found that Ruby 2.0.0 does indeed have File.write.  It's strange though that it is not listed here: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/File.html  The link you provided is for an instance method on IO objects, not a class method though (see how it only takes a string, not a filename?)  Your code works but I just can't find the documentation of File.write.

Comment: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html#method-c-write is the link to IO.write used in the above context

Comment: `IO` has both public class methods and public instance methods.  I mistakenly pointed you to the instance method.  @bjhaid has given you the reference to the class method.